# Kindling to make a fire

Tags: thermodynamics, friction

I know that rubbing stuff like dry grass or wood on firewood works to make a fire but why does it work?

I think it is because the friction produces heat but then how come our hands don't get on fire when we rub them vigorously to warm them up in cold weather? The rough texture of skin(especially in places like the palm and fingers) should make there be more friction and thus easier to kindle and get on fire than 2 smooth surfaces or a smooth surface and a rough surface.

Comment: Could you clarify what method of fire starting you're talking about? I've never seen anyone start a fire just by "rubbing dry grass on firewood".

Comment: You shouldn't overlook that starting a fire [with a fire-drill](https://www.google.com/search?q=fire+drill) (the usual friction based method) is a fairly physical enterprise: you work hard on the project even with a bow (which I've succeeded with). Doing it without a bow is even harder (I've seen it done but never managed it myself).

Comment: Shame on you, downvoter.  A question about physics is a question about physics, even if it isn't on a higher-level undergraduate or graduate school topic.

Comment: User171728 is right. Even if it is only at high school level it is still a question about physics.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because our flesh burns at a much much higher temperature than leaves, we cannot get that high a temperature using friction because we don't have enough energy (we usually stop rubbing them after a few seconds). Another problem is that even though the flesh will burn at 6-800 degrees Celsius, we still have a lot of water inside our body which will reduce oxygen consumption as well as temperature due to circulation. Compare it to some accidents that might have happened to you, when you touch a hot pan your hands font just catch fire in the same way that alcohol would at such a temperature.

BTW you also said it's cold outside so we mostly have enough energy to warm them up to about 36-37 degrees Celsius and not more because we are starting lower than if we had rubbed them on a hot summer day.